# Modal box not working for all references

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup, bootstrap-modal

So i have a 'our team' page and i want to display further info on each member when their name is clicked.

I have a modal box code, however, it only works for the first member. When i click on the other members' names, nothing pops up.

Here is the modal box html code:

```
                <div id="myModal" class="modal">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <span class="close">&times;</span>
                        <object width="100%" height="100%" data="bio/*insert member name*.pdf"></object>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

now this code is repeated for each member, and the *insert member name* part is changed to display the right pdf.

Here is the html code that references the modal box:
    Member Name

Here is the CSS code:

```
.modal {
display: none; /* Hidden by default */
position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%; /* Full width */
height: 100%; /* Full height */
overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
background-color: #fefefe;
margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
padding: 20px;
border: 1px solid #888;
width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
height: 100%
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
color: #aaa;
float: right;
font-size: 28px;
font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
cursor: pointer;
```

Here is the javascript code:

```
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Please help as i do not know what am i doing wrong.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you update the html to include the code for myBtn? It looks like you just copy pasted this from w3schools. Also, is there one modal for each member or do they all share a modal?

Comment: There is one modal for each member

Answer (score 0):

You have shared just a part of your code, but I'm assuming your loop is creating `divs` of modals.

You can create a function who receives an array of modalIds and apply the listener by id.

```js
var setupModals = function(modalIds) {
  for (var i = 0; i < modalIds.length; i++) {
    setupModalListener(modalIds[i]);
  }
};

var setupModalListener = function(modalId) {
  var modal = document.getElementById(modalId);
  // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
  var span = modal.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

  // Get the button that opens the modal
  var btn = document.getElementById(modalId + "_myBtn");

  // When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
  btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
  }

  // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
  span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }

  // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
  };
};

setupModals(['myModal', 'myModal2']);
```

```css
  .modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
}


/* Modal Content/Box */

.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto;
  /* 15% from the top and centered */
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
  height: 100%
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: #aaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
```

```html
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <object width="100%" height="100%" data="bio/*insert member name*.pdf">
    Hello world # 1
    </object>
   
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal2" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <object width="100%" height="100%" data="bio/*insert member name*.pdf">
    Hello world # 2
    </object>
    
  </div>
</div>

<button id="myModal_myBtn">Click#1</button>
<button id="myModal2_myBtn">Click#2</button>
```

**Hope it helps!**

Comment: Nice! This is helpful, the only thing I would say is that this is vulnerable to XSS injections, when the user inputs their member info. Since the JS is receiving the text directly from an input box (I'm guessing), it's fairly easy to inject a script. Otherwise, it works pretty well!